# show array list in drop down box

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to figure out how to display an array in a drop down menu from swing components. I know how to create the array of strings/integers but displaying them line by line in a drop down menu seems a little challenging.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887927/adding-items-to-a-jcombobox) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want a `JComboBox`...

[image][image]

See [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details

Or maybe you want a `JMenu` filled with `JMenuItems`

[image]

See [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more details