# Removing a wrapper class item from a JComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox

I encounter a same question that Nickolay asked in below post:
[Adding items to a JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887927/adding-items-to-a-jcombobox)

After I successfully implement the solution provided by JBuenoJr, now the question is what parameter should I put in if I need to remove an item? I tried both parameter of the ComboItem class but neither of them works.

`comboBox.removeItem(??????);`

Comment: Remove the 'wrapper' object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the whole ComboItem instead of just the key or value.

So:

`comboBox.removeItem(myComboItem)`