# How to Add Item in a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox and a class named clsPais:

```
public class clsPais {

private long id = 0;
private String nombre = "";

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombre;
    }

}
```

In my JFrame code I put:

```
clsPais p1 = new clsPais();
p1.setId(1);
p1.setNombre("ARGENTINA");

clsPais p2 = new clsPais();
p2.setId(2);
p2.setNombre("BRASIL");

cmbPaises.removeAllItems();
cmbPaises.addItem(p1);
```

Here, i have an error, telling me "incompatible types: clsPais canot be converted to string".
The addItem from my JComboBox only accept String parameter.
What can I do?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding items to a JComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887927/adding-items-to-a-jcombobox)

Comment: First of all, you may value everyone else time, and to edit your question. "What can I do?" - is not a valid question. Thanks for the understanding.

Comment: How can I value the answers? I'm new reporting here. Excuse me and Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it as follows..

```
    JComboBox<ClsPais> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();

    clsPais p1 = new clsPais();
    p1.setId(1);
    p1.setNombre("ARGENTINA");

    clsPais p2 = new clsPais();
    p2.setId(2);
    p2.setNombre("BRASIL");


    comboBox.addItem(p1);
    comboBox.addItem(p2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `cmbPaises` to be of type `clsPais` rather than `String`:

```
JComboBox<clsPais> cmbPaises = new JComboBox<>();
cmbPaises.addItem(p1);
cmbPaises.addItem(p2);
```

BTW, in Java, the convention is that class names begin with caplital letters.

Comment: With NetBeans, i had problems to redefine JComboBox type. I edit the .java with Notepadd++ and then i could change the type. Before that, it works, for every JComboBox that i need. Thanks you again.