# How to add price on an item from a binded ComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, hashtable

I'm trying to learn the difference between `Hashtable` and `HashMap` and I'm trying to add specific prices to these items here. The goal is to print the price of the item selected from `comboItem` into `txtPrice`.

```
        String[] items = {"Select Item","Betta Fish","Snail","Supplies","Food"};
        comboGroup = new JComboBox<String>(items);
        comboGroup.addActionListener(this);
        comboGroup.setBounds(130,35,150,40);
        
        comboItem = new JComboBox<>();
        comboItem.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXX");
        comboItem.setBounds(130,85,150,40);
        
        String[] subItems1 = {"Select Betta","Plakat","Halfmoon","Double Tail","Crown Tail"};
        subItems.put(items[1], subItems1);
        
        String[] subItems2 = {"Select Snail","Pond Snail","Ramshorn","Apple Snail","Assassin Snail"};
        subItems.put(items[2], subItems2);
                
        String[] subItems3 = {"Select Supply","Small Fine Net","Large Fine Net","Flaring Mirror","Aquarium Hose (1meter)"};
        subItems.put(items[3], subItems3);
        
        String[] subItems4 = {"Select Food","Daphnia","Tubifex","Mosquito Larvae","Optimum Pellets"};
        subItems.put(items[4], subItems4);
        comboGroup.setSelectedIndex(1);      
        
        //TextFields <- this is the attempt to add price to subItems value but commented out
        /*int[] items1price = {0,150,350,200,200};
        subItems.put(items[1], items1price);
        int[] items2price = {0,15,25,80,120};
        subItems.put(items[2], items2price);
        int[] items3price = {0,50,80,25,15};
        subItems.put(items[3], items3price);
        int[] items4price = {0,50,100,50,50};
        subItems.put(items[4], items4price);
        comboGroup.setSelectedIndex(1);
        */
        txtPrice = new JTextField();
        txtPrice.setBounds(130,135,150,40);
```

So far with my understanding from `HashMap` applying it to CLi and not in GUI, If I try `HashMap<String,Integer>` I can only print it altogether in a single line.

eg.

```
HashMap<String,Integer> item = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
item.put("Plakat",50);

CLi Prints:
Plakat=50
```

What I want is to print Plakat from selected `comboItem` then print `50` to `txtPrice` but I don't know how to do that.

The whole code is here: https://github.com/kontext66/GuwiPos
GUI and Main.

Additional note: I am a beginner and I'm trying to understand Layout Manager for now, so the code here is a bit messy and literal.

Comment: Looking at your code on GitHub, you put `Strings` in your `JComboBoxes`.  You can put complete Java objects in a `JComboBox`, like an item and its price.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  The section you want to focus on now is the [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) section.

Comment: *"The whole code is here:"* [Edit] to add a [mre] *here.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example using [`JComboBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to get the corresponding "prices" to specific items in the combo box. I would suggest going through the tutorial on [How to Use Various Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html) and choose the ones that suit you best. As for the difference between `HashMap` and `HashTable`, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40878). The main difference is that `HashTable` is [synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean), whereas `HashMap` is not, and since synchronization is not an issue for you, I'd suggest `HashMap`. Also, another option would be to add instances of a custom object to a `JComboBox`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887927/adding-items-to-a-jcombobox). Thus, there would be no need to use `HashMap`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class App {
    Map<String, String> map;
    JTextField tf;

    public App() {
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Plakat", "50");
        map.put("Halfmoon", "25");
        map.put("Double Tail", "80");
    }

    private void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        String[] items = { "Select Item", "Plakat", "Halfmoon", "Double Tail" };
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(items);

        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
                if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    String item = (String) event.getItem();
                    System.out.println(item);
                    tf.setText(map.get(item));
                }
            }
        });

        tf = new JTextField();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        pane.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pane.add(tf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        // frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new App().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

### Update

Below is the implementation of the second approach described earlier, where a custom object is used for adding items to a `JComboBox`, and hence, there is no need to use a `HashMap`.

P.S. I should also add that if the user shouldn't be allowed to edit the "price" in the text field, then you should use `tf.setEditable(false);`, or even use a `JLabel` instead.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class App {
    JTextField tf;

    class ComboItem {
        private String key;
        private String value;

        public ComboItem(String key, String value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return key;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    private void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        JComboBox<ComboItem> comboBox = new JComboBox<ComboItem>();
        comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("Select Item", ""));
        comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("Plakat", "50"));
        comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("Halfmoon", "25"));
        comboBox.addItem(new ComboItem("Double Tail", "80"));

        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
                if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    Object item = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    String value = ((ComboItem) item).getValue();
                    tf.setText(value);
                }
            }
        });

        tf = new JTextField();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        pane.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pane.add(tf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new App().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Update 2

To convert the string from the text field into double, you can use `Double.parseDouble(String)`, as shown below (again, make sure to use `tf.setEditable(false);`, so that the value cannot be modified by the user).

```
double price = 0;
if (tf.getText() != null && !tf.getText().trim().isEmpty())
    price = Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
System.out.println(price);
```

Comment: The cleaner way to implement your second (better) solution is to not rely on `ComboBoxItem#toString`, but to create a custom `ComboBoxRenderer`.

Comment: Hi, considering that you used String for the prices eg. "20" can String values be used in math operations? Because I will also be implementing a `(Price * Quantity)` for the `total` in the future and since "20" is considered a String and not int/double I'm wondering if there will be any conflict. Thank you for the reference of `HashMap` vs `Hashtable`, it was very informative.

Comment: @daniu I tried switching `public String getValue()` to `public int` and I get `incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int` same with the line `tf.setText(value);` I tried to add a JSpinner for the quantity and it says `non-static method setText(String) cannot be referenced from a static context`. I posted the code here on GitHub for reference to leave this post relevant to title. [here](https://github.com/kontext66/ConnectingSwings/blob/main/comboBox)

Comment: Sorry tagged the wrong person, thanks @Chris the conversion update was really helpful.